# Is there any way to maximize my application's timeslice on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, performance

I have a 3D application that needs to generate a new frame roughly every 6ms or so. This frame-rate needs to be constant in order to not result in stuttering. To make matters worse, the application has to perform several moderately-heavy calculations (mostly preparing the 3D scene and copying data  to the VRAM) so there is it consumes a fairly large amount of that ~6ms doing it's own stuff.

This has been a problem because Windows causes my application to stutter a bit when it tries to use the CPU for other things. Is there any way I could make Windows not "give away" timeslices to other processes? I'm not concerned about it negatively impacting background processes.

Comment: I can't help but think that you are going about this all wrong. There are some excellent articles by Raymond Chen on this topic which cover the dangers of trying to boost the priority of a process to the detriment of other processes which are all a good read. My take is this: The foreground process ALREADY receives a priority boost. And if other processes are stealing timeslices it is probably because the theft is necessary and you should be concerned about the impact: as those processes could be managing things like the disk cache - starving these processes will make your performance worse.

Comment: So really, your problem is not so much in the software domain as the hardware. Don't use a Pentium (or lower) for jobs like this. An i3 or i5 has enough cores to give you consistent CPU time AND allow background tasks - necessary to the performance of an application  - time to complete.

Comment: Just curious, 166 fps ?

Comment: @RichardCritten: When all your 3D modelers have received extensive training on next generation first person shooters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows will allow you to raise your application's priority. A process will normally only lose CPU time to other processes with the same or higher priority, so raising your priority can prevent CPU time from being "stolen".

Be aware, however, that if you go too far, you can render the system unstable, so if you're going to do this, you generally only want to raise priority a little bit, so it higher than other "normal" applications.

Also note that this won't make a huge difference. If you're running into small problem once in a while, increasing the priority *may* take care of the problem. If it's a constant problem, chances are that a priority boost won't be sufficient to fix it.

If you decide to try this, see [`SetPriorityClass`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686219.aspx) and [`SetThreadPriority`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686277.aspx).

Comment: I was definitely making at least *some* changes to both, but don't remember which parts were to do what...

Answer (score 1):

You can raise your process priority, but I don’t think it will help much. Instead, you should optimize your code.

For a start, use a VS built-in profiler (Debug/Performance profiler menu) to find out where your app spends most time, optimize that.

Also, all modern CPUs are at least dual core (the last single-core Celeron is from 2013). Therefore, “there it consumes a fairly large amount of that ~6ms doing it's own stuff” shouldn’t be the case. Your own stuff should be running in a separate thread, not on the same thread you use to render. [See this article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/designing-the-framework-of-a-parallel-game-engine) for an idea how to achieve that. You probably don’t need *that* level of complexity, just 2 threads + 2 tasks (compute and render) will probably be enough, but that article should give you some ideas how to re-design your app. This approach however will bring 1 extra frame of input latency (for 1 frame the background thread will compute stuff, only the next frame the renderer thread will show the result of that), but with your 165Hz rendering you can probably live with that.

Answer (score 0):

It normally depends on the scheduling algorithm used by your OS. Windows 7,8,XP,VISTA use the multilevel queue scheduling with round robin so increasing the priority of your application or thread or process will do what you want. Which version of Windows are u currently using?.. I can help u accordingly once i get to know that